# ArrayList with more than 4680 elements returning blanks

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I'm trying to turn an ArrayList to a String, and then print it. This is my code:

```
private void toString(ArrayList<Integer> answer) {
        String s = "";
        for(int i = answer.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            s = s+answer.get(i);

        }

        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

It works fine for smaller ArrayLists, but for some reason, for ArrayLists with more than 4680 elements, it returns a bunch of blank spaces. And it's NOT a problem with the String. I tried printing the characters individually to the screen, and even writing the ArrayList to a text file. Still nothing over 4680. ALSO, even weirder, if I just print the ArrayList directly to the screen, it works fine! I tried increasing the console output. Nothing. Does anybody have any idea what's happening?!?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse by any chance?

Comment: Use StringBuilder http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

Comment: USe StringBuffer instead of String

Comment: StringBuilder doesn't change anything. And yes, I'm using Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED.
It was indeed the same bug as in [Java console bug under windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354048/java-console-bug-under-windows). I set the fixed width to 400 in Eclipse and it worked. Thanks Michael Petch!

Answer (score 2):

Try to activate "Word Wrap" in the Eclipse console. It worked me.