# If i<1000,this program can run successfully ,but i change it to i<10000, this program can't run ,Why this happened?

Tags: java

Something test about Java GC

```
public class StringTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String s1;
    for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){

        s1="1";

        System.out.print(s1);

    }
  }

}
```

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: What does "can't run" mean?

Comment: Please read the [help] before posting questions.

Comment: What happens if you use println instead of print?

Comment: Any error , what is the exact problem

Comment: the console is nothing

Comment: Which console? Your shell? Windows command window? Your IDE?(Eclipse?)

Comment: This seems to be the same issue (Eclipse console related): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26182080/arraylist-with-more-than-4680-elements-returning-blanks. With `i<4680` a series of `1` is still printed, with  i>4680 no output is shown (although it seems to be there, as it can be copied with copy&paste)

Comment: You issue most likely stems from the console you are using. You are trying to print 10K characters on 1 line. It isn't really practical by any means.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue of your console (assumed Eclipse). Your program is running, and the output is shown, but for whatever reason the console can not properly handle lines of that length. In practice, it is seldom required to print such long lines. You should consider using `System.err.println()` instead of `System.err.print()` so that each iteration of your loop is printed on its own line.

However, you can also solve the issue by modifying the console settings in Eclipse:

[image: Eclipse screen shot]

By specifying a **fixed width console**, your output is properly shown (as it is wrapped at the specified console width).

Comment: Don't assume, wait until the OP has clarified the question (if ever, but that's the OP's problem)