# Read into a string (Java)

Tags: java

I'm trying to read a text file into a one single string with the following code:

```
try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (new File ("data.txt"));
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
           string += input.nextLine();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This works when the file is really small. My file is around 20 kB and it just doesn't read. I don't get any errors. What should I do? I need to read it into ONE string.

Comment: why do you need to read it into just one string?

Comment: `string += input.nextLine();` in loop is very bad practice because in each iteration you are creating new string which first needs to copy content of old string and then will add new line. To avoid such copying you should use StringBuilder.

Comment: @d.moncada because I need to find different patterns in the whole string and I can't break it down.

Comment: I'm using the StringBuilder now, and still the same thing.

Comment: Actually, it wasn't a duplicate of that. The problem was the Java console bug.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354048/java-console-bug-under-windows